# Vlookup/Index on data with gaps

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a simple data set that consists of some numbers:

```
  A   B  C  D  E  F  G

  a   1  2  3     5
  b   1  3     4     6
  c   1     2     5  6
```

I want to use a vlookup/Index formula in another sheet from this data without showing the gaps. For example in my second sheet I would like the data displayed as below:

```
  A   B  C  D  E  F  G
  a   1  2  3  5
  b   1  3  4  6
  c   1  2  5  6
```

Is there a way of doing this without copying and pasting?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this formulas.  An search of SO should turn up similar problems and solutions.

Comment: What is the maximum number of columns that contains data? or can there be any number of columns of data?

Comment: Any number of columns.

Comment: If it is not possible with any columns I can set the maximum number to 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easier ways but... Assuming data is in Sheet1, starting in A1, in A1 of the other sheet:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=0,VLOOKUP(9,$1:$1,0),Sheet1!A1)
```

drag across to G1 and A1:G1 down to Row5. Delete Row2. Select A1:G4, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., Formulas (only), tick Errors (only), <kbd>OK</kbd>, right-click within selection, Delete...,  Shift cells left, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you this does work, I was thinking if there is formula that can be used so that cells do not have to be deleted in my second sheet(Ignoring Row 2). If it is not possible then I will use the above solution.